# Web 8 ERROR TransportService - Unable to establish transport to destination

Tags: web8, transport

I have installed Web8 and get the following error on transport service. I have searched through the answers already provided for 2013 but no go.

From logs:

```
2016-02-11 16:29:56,141 ERROR TransportService - Unable to establish transport to destination.
com.tridion.transport.TransportException: Unable to retrieve destination metadata
    at com.tridion.transport.DestinationController.<init>(DestinationController.java:116) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.0-1237]
    at com.tridion.transport.DestinationControllerFactory.getDestinationController(DestinationControllerFactory.java:41) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.0-1237]
    at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.TransactionProcessor.createOrLoadTransaction(TransactionProcessor.java:134) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.0-1237]
    at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.TransactionProcessor.<init>(TransactionProcessor.java:48) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.0-1237]
    at com.tridion.transport.TransportService.handleTransaction(TransportService.java:252) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.0-1237]
Caused by: com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unknown connector type: DiscoveryService
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.pooling.TransportPoolManager.createTransporterInstance(TransportPoolManager.java:229) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.0-1237]
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.pooling.TransportPoolManager.getTransporterConnector(TransportPoolManager.java:174) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.0-1237]
    at com.tridion.transport.workers.EndpointMetaWorker.getMetadata(EndpointMetaWorker.java:32) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.0-1237]
    at com.tridion.transport.DestinationController.<init>(DestinationController.java:108) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.0-1237]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

Comment: It seems the Publisher can't connect with the "Discovery Service". Have you installed this service and have it running ok?

Comment: The DiscoveryServiceTransportConnector may have java8 features, Do you have java8 in the content manager, and it uses that version?

Comment: I am also facing same error, above sender is already in the config file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you did an upgrade from previous version, but not a clean install. In this case go to %Tridion_Home%/config/cd_transport.xml and check that you have following node in Senders section:

```
<Sender Type="DiscoveryService" Class="com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.DiscoveryServiceTransportConnector"/>
```

If it does not exist please add it and restart SDL Web Content Distributor Transport Service windows service.

Comment: I have the `<Sender Type="DiscoveryService" Class="com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.DiscoveryServiceTransportConnector"/>` in config file but still the same error