# SDL Web8.1.1 CMS : Publishing getting Failed

Tags: publishing, web8

-In cd_ambient_conf.xml OAuthEnabled="false" to avoid "invalid_grant" error.

-discovery service url running properly.No "invalid_grant" error. 
[image]

Publishing FAILED and getting below Error Logs in Transport Service Logs:

```
 2016-11-16 08:16:43,325 DEBUG TransportService - Starting handing of a transaction
    2016-11-16 08:16:43,325 TRACE TransportService - Received following request from publisher: <TransportInstructions><Transaction Id="tcm:0-6-66560" Control="Commit" /><PackageLocation>c:\Temp\tcm_0-6-66560.Content\</PackageLocation><Destinations RollbackOnFailure="false"><Destination Name="Discovery Service Upload"><DiscoveryService xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/Protocol/Discovery"><DiscoveryServiceUrl>http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc</DiscoveryServiceUrl><AuthenticationType>Anonymous</AuthenticationType></DiscoveryService></Destination></Destinations></TransportInstructions>.
    2016-11-16 08:16:43,325 INFO  TransactionProcessor - No existing transport transaction information for: tcm:0-6-66560 creating new transaction state
    2016-11-16 08:16:43,325 DEBUG TransactionHeader - Writing[TransactionHeader transactionId=tcm:0-6-66560 control=COMMIT] to C:\Temp\tcm_0-6-66560.Content\transaction.xml
    2016-11-16 08:16:43,325 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Creating new destination controller.
    2016-11-16 08:16:43,325 DEBUG DestinationController - Created Destination controller with maximum polling attempts: 900 and timeout (ms.) of: 900000
    2016-11-16 08:16:43,325 DEBUG DestinationController - Interval between polls is: 5000 ms.
    2016-11-16 08:16:43,325 DEBUG DestinationController - Maximum sending threads for destination: 5
    2016-11-16 08:16:43,340 INFO  TransportPoolManager - Creating a new TransportPoolConnector, because no available connectors in connection pool
    2016-11-16 08:16:43,340 DEBUG TransportPoolConnector - Configuring TransportPoolConnector.
    2016-11-16 08:16:43,356 ERROR TransportService - Unable to establish transport to destination.
    com.tridion.transport.TransportException: Unable to retrieve destination metadata
        at com.tridion.transport.DestinationController.<init>(DestinationController.java:116) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
        at com.tridion.transport.DestinationControllerFactory.getDestinationController(DestinationControllerFactory.java:41) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
        at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.TransactionProcessor.createOrLoadTransaction(TransactionProcessor.java:134) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
        at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.TransactionProcessor.<init>(TransactionProcessor.java:48) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
        at com.tridion.transport.TransportService.handleTransaction(TransportService.java:252) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    Caused by: com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Deployer capability not specified in: http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc
        at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.DiscoveryServiceTransportConnector.lambda$configure$1(DiscoveryServiceTransportConnector.java:81) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
        at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.DiscoveryServiceTransportConnector.configure(DiscoveryServiceTransportConnector.java:81) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
        at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.TransportPoolConnector.configure(TransportPoolConnector.java:50) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
        at com.tridion.transport.connection.pooling.TransportPoolManager.createTransporterInstance(TransportPoolManager.java:235) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
        at com.tridion.transport.connection.pooling.TransportPoolManager.getTransporterConnector(TransportPoolManager.java:174) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
        at com.tridion.transport.workers.EndpointMetaWorker.getMetadata(EndpointMetaWorker.java:32) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
        at com.tridion.transport.DestinationController.<init>(DestinationController.java:108) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
        ... 4 common frames omitted
    2016-11-16 08:16:43,356 TRACE TransportService - Sending following error to publisher: <Summary state="Failed" referenceId="tcm:0-6-66560"><Error>Unable to establish transport to destination.Unable to retrieve destination metadata</Error><Processing><Context topic="Content Delivery"><IsRollbackOnFailure/></Context></Processing><Target/></Summary>.
    2016-11-16 08:16:43,356 TRACE TransportService - HandleTransaction Took: 31
```

Comment: It seems to be the same issue as reported here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13928/web-8-error-transportservice-unable-to-establish-transport-to-destination

Comment: @NunoLinhares: Hi Nuno I have checked this but its not the same case,  i have fresh installation (not upgrade) and the cd_transport.xml has the required Sender node already: <Sender Type="DiscoveryService" Class="com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.Discovery‌​ServiceTransportConn‌​ector"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "Unable to retrieve destination metadata" indicates that publisher is not able to identify the deployer url where package is to be transferred. There could be following problems in which this type of errors will occur:

1. Discovery service url setup in topology manager is not accessible.
2. Deployer serivice is not running / not setup on the same machine on which discovery service is running.
3. Dependencies are not registered on the discovery service. To register the dependencies: if you are using web 8.1 then use Auto-Register flag for service installation and if you are on 8.0 then use `java -jar .\discovery-registration.jar sync`

Based on your question, it seems #1 is working fine so you can look for #2 and #3.

Answer (score 0):

@Hiren: point#3 you mentioned in above comment was the root cause.DeployerCapability was not registered. Below three steps fix the issue:

1)uninstall the Deployer Service using powershell cmdlet .\UninstallService.ps1

2)After this i found install script keep on failing until I explicitly update the cd_storage_conf.xml of Deployer Service to add TokenServiceUrl entry in the Configrepository Node

```
<ConfigRepository ServiceUri="http://172.24.32.50:8082/discovery.svc"
                      ConnectionTimeout="40000"
                      CacheEnabled="true"
                      CacheExpirationDuration="600"
                      ServiceMonitorPollDuration="10"
                      ClientId="registration"
                      ClientSecret="encrypted:HzfQh9wYwAKShDxCm4DnnBnysAz9PtbDMFXMbPszSVY="
                      TokenServiceUrl="http://172.24.32.50:8082/token.svc">
```

3)Install the Deployer Service using switch --auto-register. powershell command used is .\installService.ps1 --auto-register.

After this Publishing worked as SUCCESS!!!